# Get the ID of the last attached model

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I try to get the last ID of an attached model ?

My code is the following to attach the model :

```
$menu->pages()->attach($element['page_id'], array('name' => $element['name'], 'order' => $i, 'menu_page_id' => NULL));
```

But after that, I want to know the ID of the attached model because I have a foreign key "menu_page_id" which is related to the same model.

Any idea how to do that or another way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested, but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

```
$menu_page_id = $menu->pages()->wherePivot('page_id', $element['page_id'])->first()->pivot->menu_page_id;
```

Edit:

I just verified and this does indeed work for you, but only as long as you have your pages relationship setup like so...

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Page')->withPivot('menu_page_id');
}
```

Or if you don't want to do that, this should work too...

```
$menu_page_id = $menu->pages()->withPivot('menu_page_id')->wherePivot('page_id', $element['page_id'])->first()->pivot->menu_page_id;
```

Comment: this will not work if there are multiple pivot records with the same page_id and menu_id.

Comment: i know its an old question but i am struggling with it.
I dont understand the answer. The question is if an id can be returned with the attch function? maybe i did misunderstood. as the answer is indeed NOT working if the page_id is not unique (as in my case). So on the attach there is no option to retreive the inserted id in the same call? (laravel 8)